# Why does IE11 block onclick events for trusted sites when internet zone security is set to high?

Tags: javascript, html, security, internet-explorer, onclick

I work on a site in a development environment where IT frequently resets our IE internet zone security settings to High. I'm finding that onclick events for html input buttons do not fire, even though I've added sites to the trusted sites zone. For example if I go to jsfiddle.net and run:

```
<input type="button" value="edit" onclick="alert('blah')" />
```

It won't fire even though jsfiddle.net is in the trusted zone. Once I drop the internet zone back to Medium-High, it's dandy. Is there a workaround for this? Or is there another security setting that I'm missing or some IT activity that might block it?

Comment: Doesn't that setting block all JavaScript from running? Don't have IE at hand to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle code runs in the context of `fiddle.jshell.net` not `jsfiddle.net`. Add `fiddle.jshell.net` to the trusted zone.

`fiddle.jshell.net` is the sandbox domain of JSFiddle to prevent JavaScript untrused code execution on the main domain.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that does fix jsfiddle. I still have issues with localhost when testing with visual studio and when accessing our website from inside our internal network. I'll have to try outside our network to see if I have the same issue with the website. I have the proxy setting in IE bypassing the proxy for local addresses so I would think that eliminates proxy issues for visual studio/localhost, but I would be wrong. :)